# Another X-Server failsafe question

Tags: unity, graphics, xorg

Updated from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04. Seems to have gone fine. On reboot I get the Ubuntu animation with the dots, then I get a low video mode dialog. I cannot get out of it, it has an infinite loop (definitly a bug by itself). Then I switch over to tty1 and log in. I can do startx and my desktop comes up, my icons are as I had them before the upgrade, but there is no launcher, windows have no decorations, and I cannot change between windows, only the last opened window is active. Otherwise things work fine, including the screen resolution.

I went through all the suggestions I could find. Reinstalled unity, lightdm, tried other managers, desktops. I even deleted xorg.conf so that it would be regenerated, but it wasn't: it is always xorg.failsafe that is generated.

So it looks to me that for some reason X-Server always wants to boot into failsafe mode. Probably because of the graphical login prompt, since the animation before that works, and the X-Server after that also works.

I haven't found anything reasonable in the X-Server logs.

Where should I look for a solution? I really don't want to reinstall my OS, the upgrade took a long time already, and I've spent two days trying to fix it.

(onboard NVidia video, if that matters, but since the video itself works fine, it is probably not the issue, but you can never know)

Answer (score 0):

You should reinstall your graphic card driver. Recently I've upgraded a computer with Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 that was using Nvidia graphic card driver supplied by Nvidia website (not from official ubuntu's repo). It just crashed like you reported. I fixed this by overriding the driver by the supplied in Ubuntu's repositories. I just make shure that I was using the same version available to my graphic card in nvidia download page.

Following images can illustrate the process.

[Finding by apropriate graphic card version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gapqu.png)

[Getting the apropriate version number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7d4S.png)

In my case, i just typed

```
 # apt-get install nvidia-361
```

Obviously, accessing root shell in repair console, with network enabled and rw access to / partition.

Comment: It didn't work, but it was interesting. I already had nvidia-current installed. When I installed nvidia-361 startx didn't work. I removed it, then startx worked again. Then I removed nvidia-current and startx still works.

Isn't it the case that the nvidia driver is no longer needed because nouveau includes the necessary drivers by default?

Comment: Which graphic card you use? Nouveau shouldn't be enable. It should be replaced by nvidia driver. Can you tell me which driver is being loaded?

just type

     lsmod | grep nvidia

and paste here the output

Comment: @arthu.afarias Here it is.

    uvcvideo               90112  0  
    videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo  
    videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc  
    videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo  
    videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2   
    v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2  
    videodev              176128  4     uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2  
    media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev  
    video                  40960  1 i915

Comment: First paste here  "lsmod | grep nouveau" output. After, paste here "lsmod | grep nvidia".

Comment: Both are empty.

Comment: Let me see which graphic cards are installed by typing "lspci | grep VGA"

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)

Comment: There is no Nvidia Graphic Card installed in your computer. Not even onboard. The only graphic controller installed is the integrated intel described by lspci entry that you shown.

Comment: Correct, that is all I have. I'm sure I had the nvidia driver in 14.04, I even had the repeated issues of having to reinstall it after every kernel upgrade, until that problem got fixed.

Comment: You shouldn't have any Nvidia driver installed. You can uninstall them all by typing sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

Comment: In order to start helping you I would like to see two more outputs, I recommend pasting them in pastebin.com

"dmesg"
"sudo systemctl status lightdm"

dmseg command will produce too much output I recomend redirecting the buffer to a file

"dmesg > dmesg.out.txt"

Comment: Paste here the urls from pasted outputs

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VrH10FqK

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wejk0muw

Comment: Through all this launching startx directly still works (with the missing bits mentioned in the question).

Comment: Would you paste (use pastebin again) contents of the files "/var/log/lightdm/x-*-greeter.log"? where * is a number varying from 0 to n.

Comment: I would like to see which kernel modules are blacklisted too. To that you should paste here the results of "ls /etc/modprobe.d/".

Comment: Could you check if "/var/lib/lightdm" folder exists? create it and grant permissions to lightm:lightdm by executing following command "sudo mkdir /var/lib/lightdm && sudo chown -R lightdm:lightdm /var/lib/lightdm && chmod 0750 /var/lib/lightdm" Try rebooting and see what happens. If nothing happens, you should paste "x-*-greeter.log" to see what is happening.

Comment: And that was it. /var/lib/lightdm didn't exist. I created it with the right permissions, force reinstalled lightdm, and it works now. Thanks for the help